# Ruby Rails app: After deleting OmniAuth gem and omniauth.rb, OmniAuth unitialized constant and rake aborted when attempt deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, initialization, omniauth

**Resolved** --> use git commit -A or git commit . in correct directory

**What happened before:**

I included OmniAuth gem in Gemfile, created omniauth.rb in config/initializer folder, used $bundle install.

I realized I didn't want to use the OmniAuth gem so I **removed its line from the Gemfile** and **deleted the omniauth.rb file**.

I've also removed the following line from the **config/application.rb** file just in case:

> config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)

I ran $bundle update in hopes of updating everything.

**Now:**

App does work on local server, but when I try to deploy to heroku with $git push heroku, the deployment aborts and part of the resulting message is:

> ```
>   Running: rake assets:precompile
>   rake aborted!
>   uninitialized constant OmniAuth
>   /tmp/build_34578113-b133-4234-b473-3cd6bc4872ca/config/initializer/omniauth.rb:1:in >`<top (required)>
>
>   Tasks: TOP => environment
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
> ```

I've checked and there is no omniauth.rb file in my config/initializer folder, and no swap versions either.

Does anyone know why the system still thinks OmniAuth is still there and what can I do to get rid of it? Might I have missed something? Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that you committed your latest changes?

Comment: You caught it. So stupid of me to not use git commit -A. I've been using git commit . Thanks